# How do I reactivate that the 3 axes for moving an object move with the object? :D

Tags: modeling, objects, interface

So my english isn´t the best so the upper formulation was the best I could write xD. When you move an object for example 3 Units to the right, the 3 axes also move 3 Units to the right. But in the Project I´m currently working on(IPhone SE or something like that) the axes now always stay at the global Center which is pretty annoying, and I have had this Problem for a few times already and I never found the solution :X

Comment: Sounds like your pivot point is set to 3D cursor. If  you press `Ctrl` + `,` (comma), does that fix it?

Comment: Yeaaaah! thx! Thats it ;)